# Simple case about Zariski closure

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X = V(P)$: algebraic variety

$f, g \in \mathbb{C}[X_1,...,X_n]$

and $X_0 = \{x \in X |g(x) \neq0$ or $f(x) \neq 0$ }

then Zariski closure of $X_0$ is just $X$?

Since $X_0$ is just a union of two Zariski open sets, and a Zariski open set can be regarded as just a complementary set of the finite number of points, I can imagine that its closure is likely to be the whole of X. But could you explain it a little more properly?

Comment: This is incomprehensible, -1.

Comment: @HankScorpio I can comprehend the question. In other words, it says: Let $X = V(p) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n_\mathbb{C}$ be an affine variety, and let $f, g \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, ... x_n]$ and define $X_0 = \{x \in X : f(x) \neq 0 $ or $g(x) \neq 0 \}$. Then, is the closure of $X_0$ in the Zariski topology equal to $X$?

Comment: @DavidLui $p$ is not defined. When I wrote the comment, neither $f$ nor $g$ were defined either. Saying "a Zariski open set can be regarded as just a complementary set of the finite number of points" is also false in general, so that would give me pause at guessing too much about what the author meant with other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. For example, if $X$ is a single point and $f$ or $g$ vanish at that point, then $X_0$ is empty so the closure of $X_0$ is not $X$.

Comment: Assuming $X_0$ is non-empty, is that correct?

Comment: Then yes, since non empty open sets are dense in an irreducible space.

Comment: ”non empty open sets are dense in an irreducible space.” This is exactly the statement I wanted. (it is describing my image mathematically). Thank you!